# In which date format should the Date column of my SQL Table be created to accept this specific date format?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I need to create a Table with a date column. This column will receive an automatic input from a software on a daily basis. This software has the flexibility to connect with that SQL Table on my database and to feed it with its output.

My issue is that the date in the output column of the software is as follows: `2019-11-11 16:41:03`

I have created my SQL Table and created a "DateReceived" column in the `datetime` format. However, when I try to create the mapping in the software with my SQL Table, it can't match its date column with the "DateReceived"column of my SQL Table.

Unfortunately, I can't edit the output from the software to format the date. My only solution is to format the "DateReceived" column in my SQL table appropriately. However, I am confused why the `datetime` format is not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "is not working" actually means here?  `'2019-11-11 16:41:03'` is a valid datetime literal in SQL Server.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The software does not show me my "DateReceived" column in its drop down list to match against its datetime column. So, I am assuming there is a mismatch in terms of date formatting.

Comment: Well maybe you need to cast your `datetime` to a `date` first, and then do the comparison.  Or, perhaps compare the date to a range of datetimes.

Comment: when you say "This software has the flexibility to connect" what do you mean? are you inserting a *datetime* or are you inserting a text and SqlServer adapts it as it sees fit to datetime? Because if you are sending in text, you are opening yourself up to a bunch of problems. One person might send in "2019-11-31" which is a blatant error, and another might send in "2019-11-14" which might also be a problem if your datetime is set to receive yyyy-dd-MM input.

Comment: SQL doesn't store `date` and `datetime` values in a text format. You're probably running up against [`DATEFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql) which affects the default text-to-date and date-to-text conversion formats.

Comment: @LongChalk The datetime output by the software is automatically generated by it. No human input. Basically, I need to a create a column with the "right format" to receive the data. I have tried formatting my SQL Table column as "datetime" but the software isn't doing the mapping correctly.

Comment: @user3115933 then you need to go "inside the software" and have it send a *datetime* and not a string. There is no "correct text format" for datetime. datetime is datetime. There are over 100 countries and each of them marks dates a little bit different.

Comment: Where is the problem? Does SQL Server have problems reading the data or does the software have problems? Do you exchange data in both directions?